# Rails error messages not showing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails...but I'm trying to do an app on my own to "practice" what I've learned.

I have a new form with model validations, but the error messages aren't showing. Here is what I have:

`seed.rb` (Model)

```
class Seed < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :category, presence: true
    validates :latin, presence: true
    validates :maturity, presence: true
    validates :sun, presence: true
    validates :sow, presence: true
    validates :cycle, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 500 }
    mount_uploader :seedimage, SeedImageUploader
end
```

`seed_controller.rb` (Controller)

```
  class SeedsController < ApplicationController    
    def index
       @seeds = Seed.all 
    end

    def new
       @seed = Seed.new
    end

    def create
      @seed = Seed.new(seed_params) 
      if @seed.save
        redirect_to seeds_path
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    def edit

    end

    def update
       @seed = Seed.find(params[:id])  
       if @seed.update(seed_params)
           redirect_to @seed
       else
            render 'edit'
       end
    end

    def show
      @seed = Seed.find(params[:id])  
    end

    def destroy
      @seed = Seed.find(params[:id])
      @seed.destroy

      redirect_to seeds_path
    end

    def seed_params
      params.require(:seed).permit(:name, :category, :latin, :maturity, :sun, :sow, :cycle, :description, :seedimage)
    end

  end
```

`_form.html.erb` (Form for 'New') (`new.html.erb` just has `<% render 'form' %>`

```
<%= form_with model: @seed, class: "form-horizontal" do |f| %>

  <% if @seed.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@seed.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this seed from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @seed.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Seed Name" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :category %>
    <%= f.text_field :category, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Category: 'beans'" %>
    </div>
    <div class="control-label">
    <%= f.label :latin %>
    <%= f.text_field :latin, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Latin Name" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :maturity %>
    <%= f.number_field :maturity, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Maturity Time" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :sun %>
    <%= f.select(:sun, options_for_select([['Full Sun'], ['Partial Sun'], ['Full Shade']]), {}, { class: "custom-select"})  %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :sow %>
    <%= f.text_field :sow, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Plant Indoors/Sow Outdoors/etc.." %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :cycle %>
    <%= f.text_field :cycle, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Annual/Perennial/etc.." %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %>
     <%= f.text_area :description, size: "60x12", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :seedimage %>
     <%= f.file_field :seedimage, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm a bit confused why this doesn't work? Right now when I hit the create button it flashes, but no error messages. I can CONFIRM that the model is using the validations because if I try to do a `Seed.create()` and check messages against that it doesn't indeed work....so I'm a bit confused?

From what I can tell the `.any?` isn't happening, since if I do a `!` to that statement it'll at least display `0 messages`.

Comment: wondering if your view\layouts\application.html.erb has the code to flash messages?

Comment: @olucube Nope, it's all just in the `_form` partial right now

Comment: @MZaragoza It seems like im not, because even putting test messages under that if statement won't work. BUT I know the model is working correctly because I can get error messages when creating a blank in console.

Comment: Also I can clearly see data rolled back due to the model validations in the console logs.

Comment: @MZaragoza i actually tried checking in the controller that (if true then going to 'index') but it appears thats not working (or becoming true at least)....so that's not getting set for some reason.

Comment: Not sure why it'd work when doing it in console but not otherwise...

Comment: @MZaragoza I guess in the view, but it doesn't appear to be seeing it in the controller either when doing a `if @seed.errors.any?` . So im not sure why thats not getting set to true. Even though the data is getting clearly rolled back.

Comment: I would if I could at this moment. :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not seeing any error messages because all the forms generated by `form_with` tag are `remote: true` by default and send xhr(ajax) requests to  the server. If you want to see the error messages, as of your current setup, you have to add `local: true` wich makes the submission normal.
Replacing

```
<%= form_with model: @seed, class: "form-horizontal" do |f| %>
```

with

```
<%= form_with model: @seed,  local: true, class: "form-horizontal" do |f| %>
```

will do the trick. Hope this will help.

Comment: Ah dang! that was it. Thanks!